# How to find image src which is next in list of images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my code like this for the image gallery

```
<div id="panel">
   <div id="img-grp-wrap">
       <div class="img-wrap">
            <img id="largeImage" src="images/1_large.jpg" />
            <div id="description">1st image description</div>
       </div>

       <img src="arrowright.jpg" class="next" alt="Next"/> 
       <img src="arrowleft.jpg" class="prev" alt="Previous"/>

   </div>
</div>

<div id="thumbs" class="content mThumbnailScroller">
<ul>
   <li><img src="images/ind_thumb.jpg" alt="1st image description" /></li>
   <li><img src="images/pak_thumb.jpg" alt="2nd image description" /></li>
   <li><img src="images/sl_thumb.jpg" alt="3rd image description" /></li>
   <li><img src="images/nz_thumb.jpg" alt="4th image description" /></li>
   <li><img src="images/ban_thumb.jpg" alt="5th image description" /></li>
   <li><img src="images/uae_thumb.jpg" alt="6th image description" /></li>
   <li><img src="images/sa_thumb.jpg" alt="7th image description" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript code as

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    var curr = $('#largeImage').attr('src');
    curr = curr.replace('large','thumb');

    var next = $('#thumbs li').next('img[src=' + curr + ']').attr('id');
    alert(next);

});

if curr value is "images/ban_thumb.jpg". so i want to alert next value to be
```

"images/uae_thumb.jpg" i.e the next image src and same for the previous img src of curr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These will find the next and previous image sources.  Note you need quotes for the `src` attribute since it has a slash:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
  var curr = $('#largeImage').attr('src');
  curr = curr.replace('large','thumb');

  var next = $('img[src="' + curr +'"]')
              .parent('li')
              .next()
              .find('img').attr('src');
  alert(next);
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
  var curr = $('#largeImage').attr('src');
  curr = curr.replace('large','thumb');

  var prev = $('img[src="' + curr + '"]')
              .parent('li')
              .prev()
              .find('img').attr('src');
  alert(prev);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the images (You could use an array for this) and then populate the array by finding all of the images within the `DOM`.

When the button is clicked you can use the array and retrieve the image source, for instance.

```
var arr = [];
var count = 0;

$("#thumbs li img").each(function() {
   var item = $(this).attr("src");
   arr.push(item);
});

$(".next").click(function() {
    $("input").val(arr[count]);
    count++;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oo7sdjdm/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution with some good practices like using ID, grouping variables, caching the jQuery Object .. We'll use a counter to get the next and previous and a small function to get the image by index et voilà:

```
var i = 0, // Counter
    $images = $('#thumbs').find('img'), // Cache the jQuery object
    total = $images.length,
    getCurrentItem = function () {
        var currentItem = Math.abs(i % total), // Get item index
            $currentItem = $images.eq(currentItem), // Current item object
            currentItemSrc = $currentItem.attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large');
        alert(currentItemSrc);
    };

$('.next').on('click', function () {
    i++;
    getCurrentItem();
});

$('.prev').on('click', function () {
    i--;
    if (i < 0) {
        i = total - 1; // If negative go back to the last image
    }
    getCurrentItem();
});
```